# RxJS - Conditionally add observable in a pipe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, rxjs

So i have a function like below

```
showLoader = () => <T>(source: Observable<T>) => {
  LoaderService.loadPage.next(true);
  return source.pipe(
    finalize(() => {
        LoaderService.loadPage.next(false);
    })
  );
};
```

And then i use it while making HTTP calls like below

```
return this.http.get(url).pipe(showLoader())
```

But let's say i encounter a scenario where i need the loader or any observable for that matter based on a condition; something like below

```
const loader : boolean = false
return this.http.get(url).pipe(concat(...), loader ? showLoader() : of(values))
```

I tried using the `iif` operator like below

```
const loader : boolean = false
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(concat(...), mergeMap(v => iif(() => loader, showLoader(), of(v))))
```

and got the following error

> TS2345: Argument of type '(source: Observable) => Observable'
> is not assignable to parameter of type 'SubscribableOrPromise<{}>'.

Can someone hep me understand where i am going wrong and how to rectify the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do it like this:

```
showLoader = (show: boolean = true) => <T>(source: Observable<T>) => {
  if (!show) { // just go straight to source
    return source;
  }

  return defer(() => { // defer makes sure you don't show the loader till actually subscribed
    LoaderService.loadPage.next(true);
    return source.pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        LoaderService.loadPage.next(false);
      })
    )
  })
};
```

use:

```
return this.http.get(url).pipe(showLoader(false))
```

but the way you seem to be statically accessing `LoaderService` reeks of design issues and bugs in your future. FYI.

Comment: That's actually better than my answer

Comment: @bryan60 The loaderService uses DI and is injected in the constructor. Or if you are suggesting using Httpinterceptor for this? If it is not a problem can you brief me about the design issue ?

Comment: The design issue is that you seem to have this function using LoaderService static methods. You should not be using static methods. They will cause issues as you are working outside of the DI framework by doing that.

Comment: Thank you so much @bryan60. It was right infront of my eyes and i couldn't notice. Will be making the changes :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like following:

```
const startWithTap = (callback: () => void) =>
  <T>(source: Observable<T>) => of({}).pipe(
    startWith(callback),
    switchMap(() => source)
  );

const showLoader = () => <T>(source: Observable<T>) => concat(
  iif(
    () => loader,
    source.pipe(
      startWithTap(() => LoaderService.loadPage.next(true)),
      finalize(() => {
        LoaderService.loadPage.next(false);
      })
    ),
    EMPTY
  ), source);

return this.http.get(url).pipe(
  showLoader()
);
```

Comment: We have used the showLoader function in a lot of places and hence we will need to be changing all pipes to pass source. is there a way to pass the source explicitly ?

Comment: you should use `defer` instead of that `startWithTap` function.

Comment: Thank you @GogaKoreli for the help